# Why 'src' raise warning in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

This will raise error:

```
<img
    src={'https://themekit.dev/shared/thumbs/wide.png'}
    alt="cover image"
/>
```

this not:

```
<img
    alt="cover image"
/>
```

I have domain enabled in next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: [
            'themekit.dev',
```

here the whole component:

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/ImageUpload.module.css'
import {
    updateClientAndServer,
    uploadImage,
    useValueFromKeyPath,
} from 'tikexModule/slice'
import { useAppDispatch } from 'tikexModule/hooks/useAppDispatch'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

interface ImageUploadProps {
    bucket: string
    keyPath: string[]
    title?: string
    srcFallback?: string
    width?: number
    height?: number
}
const ImageUpload2 = ({
    bucket,
    keyPath,
    title,
    srcFallback,
    width,
    height,
}: ImageUploadProps) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const keyPath2 = keyPath
    const imgId = useValueFromKeyPath(keyPath)

    return (
        <>
            <input
                type="file"
                id="actual-btn"
                onChange={(e) => {
                    const imgIdNew = uuid()
                    dispatch(
                        uploadImage({
                            props: {
                                imageKey: imgIdNew,
                                bucket: bucket,
                                imageKeyPrev: imgId,
                            },
                            file: e.target.files[0],
                            andThen: () => {
                                dispatch(
                                    updateClientAndServer({
                                        keyPath: keyPath,
                                        value: imgIdNew,
                                        operation: 'setValue',
                                        valuePrev: imgId,
                                    })
                                )
                            },
                        })
                    )
                }}
                hidden
            />
            <label
                className={title ? 'btn btn-sm btn-circle' : 'img-box'}
                htmlFor="actual-btn"
            >
                <img
                    src={'https://themekit.dev/shared/thumbs/wide.png'}
                    alt="cover image"
                />
            </label>
        </>
    )
}

export default ImageUpload2
```

```
next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Extra attributes from the server: style
    at img
    at label
    at ImageUpload2 (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/components/ImageUpload2.tsx:17:24)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at SurveySchema (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/pages/dashboard/organizations/[organizationId]/posts/[postId]/index.tsx:22:72)
    at div
    at Page (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/components/Dashboard/Page/index.tsx:15:26)
    at div
    at div
    at section
    at main
    at Layout (webpack-internal:///./components/Layout.tsx:11:26)
    at DashboardLayout (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/components/Dashboard/DashboardLayout.tsx:22:26)
    at DashboardProvider (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/components/Dashboard/DashboardContext.tsx:46:26)
    at WrapperComponent
    at AppProvider (webpack-internal:///./tikexModule/AppContext.tsx:50:26)
    at Provider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:13:3)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:96:27)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/client.js:8:20746)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/client.js:8:23395)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:323:9)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:849:26)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:973:27)
```

Comment: Use `next/image` instead. (Change `img` to `Image`.)

Comment: Change, got an other warning

Comment: What is the warning you get?

Comment: Please chech last update in post: `Warning: Extra attributes from the server: style`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403718/5385381

Comment: Also check this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22388